# Android Trying to query data but its not returning anything

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to query data. I confirmed that data is being inserted into the database. I tried dumping the query to the log but it doesn't show anything. It never goes into the while loop only the finally. There should be a total of 4 rows in the table being returned.

```
private void queryCol(String t)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "IN queryCol");
    final String     TABLE_NAME = "CInfo";

    String[] projection = {"col1"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            true,
            TABLE_NAME,                               // The table to query
            projection,                               // The columns to return
            null,                                     // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // don't group the rows
            null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
            null,                                     // The sort order
            null,
            null
    );

try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "in while");
        String s = DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor);
        cinfo.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(term)));    //cinfo is an arrayList
        Log.d(TAG, s);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Exception " + e);
}
finally {
    Log.d(TAG, "in finally");
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: add `catch` and print/log `Exception` if present

Comment: @snachmsm I updated the original post with the catch block and there is no exception.

Comment: Shouldn't you move the cursor to the first position before the while loop?

Comment: if you `Log.d` the value of `cursor.getCount()` you would see `0` meaning there is no rows queried, BTW if you want to see your `cursor` data just call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);`

Comment: @pskink I just got the count and its 0. I guess something is wrong with my query.